# Is there any automatically adjustable stand for camera?

Tags: automation, face-detection, support-equipment

When I have a container for taking photo that detects person when he/she enters it by PIR sensor, and I want to install camera that will be connected to the PC, that detects face of that person and takes a photo.

The problem is it may be a small child or tall adult. How can I automatically adjust the height at which the camera takes an image?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is photography related either.  Sounds more like some type of robotics or engineering problem than a photography problem.

Comment: @AJHenderson The question seems to be about solving the same class of problems addressed by movements on technical cameras. It is only its phrasing as an XY problem that seems to put it off topic.

Comment: @benrudgers - except it isn't just about how to move a camera up and down.  It's primarily about building a system to move it up or down automatically.  That automation piece is what pushed it over the edge.  The question is "how do a I build a robot that can move something up and down on it's own?"  it just happens to be moving a camera.  If it is asking for a specific device, it is a product recommendation, if it is not, it is not photography related.

Comment: Put another way, let's take it to the extreme.  "My subject may move around.  How do I build a vehicle that can follow them?"  Is building a self-driving subject tracking car on topic for Photo.SE?  If we apply that logic, we can make just about anything "photography" related.

Comment: @AJHenderson I see the problem as photographing subjects at different heights. Deciding to move the camera is what turns it into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Moving the lens is another solution to photographing subjects of varying height and well within the realm of photography. Cropping is similarly.

Comment: @benrudgers - Under that approach to an XY problem, the problem would be "what camera movement can I make to adjust for subjects of different heights?" I agree that such a question would be on topic, however it has no apparent bearing to the OP's desire to have an automated solution that can do this without intervention.  The answer to such a question might be able to help him indirectly in making sure he makes his robot do the right thing, but there is no way we can cover the core of this question as asked, which is primarily focused on the automation of a platform.

Comment: Personally, I chose not to edit it to "what camera movement can I make to adjust for subjects of different heights" because I believe his pedestal approach likely is the best, so it seems like a question he doesn't actually have, even if it is the most we can offer him within our context.

Comment: @AJHenderson I edited the question to something that I think meets the guidelines and still includes the photographic problem while not curtailing the engineering tradeoffs of the application  in so far as it is described. So long as the question is closed, the internet cannot get better...it probably does not do much for this site's new user experience either. New user experience seems to be something StackExchange is trying to improve these days.

Comment: Yes, it is really seems a bit off topic here.

Comment: @jclean I've been asking over at the robotics se to see if they can help, but wanted to verify they can before I edit it and migrate it over.  Do you think a response from them on how to build a system to do what you are looking for would be helpful for your needs?

Comment: @AJHenderson I have asked question on robootics https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/is-there-any-automatically-height-adjusting-stand-for-camera yesterday. But no one replied yet.

Answer (score 3):

For a number of applications, this issue is often solved by using a dedicated PTZ Camera, which has a camera with a zoom lens integrated with a motor-driven and controllable pan+tilt head. Most of these cameras nowadays are also IP cameras that can be controlled via network or IoT standard interfaces.

In surveillance, these cameras are often mounted upside down from a ceiling, some distance away from the target area to be monitored. This reduces the maximum sweep angle needed to adjust for the height of the individual entering the surveillance zone, and also avoids a potential issue where the PTZ might not be able to look down at a subject (the way standing adults address children) if it were mounted right-side-up, as the sweep area for the tilt is typically from parallel to the base to straight up.

Comment: Panning and tilting will change the perspective in a portrait. For example a child will have to look up at a camera that would be eye level for an adult. That may or may not be an issue for the application envisioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should find your way out. Ideally the camera should be mounted on a vertically mounted bar which could move to and fro with the help of gears. The gears could be moved with a stepper motor controlled by a arduino based hardware and software.

Comment: It means that there is no ready one, right? I should make it myself from scratch.

Comment: There definitely are surveillance camera systems that do advanced face tracking. Not sure how many of them are affordable as those I have seen are usually part of large surveillance installation with hundreds of cameras. I think, however, that the previous answer about PTZ cameras is the first stop to look at.